# Let $A''=\operatorname{End}_{A'}(V)=\operatorname{End}_{\operatorname{End}_A(V)}(V)$. Show that $A''$ is a $k$-algebra.

Tags: representation-theory

> Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra for a field $k$. And let $V$ be a representation of $A$.
>   Define  $A''=\operatorname{End}_{A'}(V)=\operatorname{End}_{\operatorname{End}_A(V)}(V)$. Show that $A''$ is a $k$-algebra.

$\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}$
**Context.**
Doing an exercise to prepare for my exams. I actually think I kind of solved this while asking the question, but posting this, for the chance someone can put some more light on this problem, or spot erros in my reasoning.

**Effort.**
To show that $A''$ is a $k$-algebra, it suffices to show that there exists a ring homomorphism
$$
f: k \rightarrow  Z(A'').
$$
To show that $f$ is a ringhomomorphism it suffices to show that

1. $f(\alpha )\circ L=L\circ f(\alpha ) \qquad \forall \alpha \in k,\  \forall L\in \End_{A'}(V)$
2. $f(\alpha )+f(\beta )=f(\alpha +\beta ) \qquad \forall \alpha ,\beta \in k$
3. $f(\alpha )f(\beta )=f(\alpha \beta ) \qquad \forall \alpha ,\beta \in k$

So I think first condition forces $f(\alpha )$ to be a scalar of $I_{A''}$. But what are the scalars in $A'=\End_A(V)$ ? So if understand correctly the scalars in $A$ are $\alpha 1_A$. So are the scalars in $A'$ then $\alpha 1_AI_{A'}$? If that is true if would define
$$
f:k \rightarrow Z(A'') : \alpha \mapsto \alpha 1_AI_{A'}I_{A''}
$$

Stil seems a bit weird to me. Condition 2 and 3 seems kind of trivial with this definition, but at the same time I feel kind of overwhelmed, and like I don't understand it completely. So maybe they are not trivial.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the notation. What is A, what is V,...? [Of course, one can somehow guess, but still.]

Comment: @quid You are right, just forgot it, updated it now.

Comment: Endomorphisms of a module over a ring always form an algebra over the ring (that act on the original module on the right.) This is because you can always add two endomorphisms, compose two endomorphisms or multiply an endomorphism by a scalar in the ring. Thus, $\text{End}_\text{End_{A} (V)} (V)$ is an algebra over $\text{End_{A}(V)}$ which in turn is an algebra over $A$ which is a $k$-algebra. You're reasoning seems pretty solid. Conditions 2 and 3 are always more or less trivial in such a case.